# How to modify several range references in a Spreadsheet synchronously?

Tags: google-sheets

There are 20 cells that have functions like this:

```
A1 =index('sheet2'!$A$1:$B$3)

C1 =index('sheet3'!$A$1:$B$3)

E1 =index('sheet4'!$A$1:$B$3)
```

So in each function, only the sheet number changes, but the range remains.

My problem is:
I want to change the range (e.g. from `A1:B3` to `C1:D3`) of all functions, but don't want to change them one by one, is there any convenient ways to modify all of them at once?

Comment: Related: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/88177/does-google-sheets-have-sheet-level-named-ranges

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the range reference a string parameter by using `indirect`. Example: cell X1 contains text `$A$1:$B$3`, cell A1 contains the formula

```
=index(indirect("Sheet2!" & X1))
```

and similarly for other cells. Then if you change the content of X1, all range references change accordingly.

(You don't actually need the `index` part if the formula is as it appears here, but I suppose your real spreadsheet had more parameters.)

Comment: An additional question: could I do the same way when using =importrange ?

Comment: If yes, what would be the function? I tried something like =importrange(indirect("xxxxxxx", "sheet1! &A1") but it becomes #N/A. Please tell me no matter it is possible or not. Thanks!

Comment: With importrange it's easier because the range reference is already a string, you don't `indirect`. It's just `=importrange("key", "sheet1" & A1)`

Comment: Really thank you for the help, just one last question- if I want to change all reference sheets synchronously (i.e. change all "sheet1!" to "sheet2!"), is it possible to do?