# Google Sheets getRangeByName isn't working after duplicating sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I use the following function to duplicate a sheet, and it works great.

```
function duplicateDataSheet() {
  const date = getTodayDateAsString();  
  const newDataName = `${date}_data`;
  const oldDataName = 'data';
  Logger.log(`newDataName = ${newDataName}`);
  const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName(oldDataName), true);
  spreadsheet.duplicateActiveSheet();
  const newDataSheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();  
  newDataSheet.setName(newDataName);
};
```

The sheet named 'data' has a Named Range called 'csv_paste_area'.

After duplicating the sheet, I then call a custom function of mine:

```
clearRangeByName('csv_paste_area');
```

**But it ends up clearing the range of the most recently duplicated version of the 'data' sheet rather than the *true* 'csv_paste_area' Named Range, which exists on the original 'data' sheet!**

This has been driving me crazy!

It feels like a bug in Google Sheets. I wonder if there is a work-around.

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured out a work-around.

I updated my `clearRangeByName` function to accept an optional `sheetName` argument:

```
function clearRangeByName(rangeName, sheetName = null) {
  Logger.log(`clearRangeByName: ${rangeName}`);
  const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const originalActiveSheetName = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getSheetName();
  if (sheetName && sheetName !== originalActiveSheetName) { // because of this weirdness https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/89963/27487
    spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName));
  }
  const range = spreadsheet.getRangeByName(rangeName);
  clearData(range); // custom function
  if (sheetName && sheetName !== originalActiveSheetName) { // because of this weirdness https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/89963/27487
    spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName(originalActiveSheetName));
  }
}
```

Then I call it like `clearRangeByName('csv_paste_area', 'data');`

Thanks to https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/89963/27487 for the hint.

### Update

Actually, I found a [bug reported in 2013](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36758232) (which linked to https://stackoverflow.com/a/15823668/470749, by the way) where Google said they would clarify documentation at https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getRangeByName(String), which now says:

> **getRangeByName(name)**
> Returns a named range, or `null` if no range with
> the given name is found. If multiple sheets of the spreadsheet use the
> same range name, specify the sheet name without additional quotation
> marks — for example, `getRangeByName('TaxRates')` or
> `getRangeByName('Sheet Name!TaxRates')`, but not `getRangeByName('"Sheet Name"!TaxRates')`.

So I can remove the clunky `if` statements from my `clearRangeByName` function and just use a scoped range name when calling `getRangeByName`.